# css doesnt load on my wordpress site on host

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, indexing

i have a word press site
a point about the loading css files; when i want to change the main color of site i see that my faviorit color is there and i just should click on save bottun but when i click it dosnt load,it loads and at the end it goes on this url that it isnt any thing there just an url:
http://bourssanj.com/bours/wp-admin/admin.php?page=of-topbar-menu&settings-updated=true

this is my site: bourssanj.com/bours

whats problem?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Chrome's developer tools, or Firefox's Firebug? Just by opening the developer tools I looked at your code and I found, for example, this:

`<img src="http://localhost:81/bours/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/dt-016.jpg" alt="">`

Where is this being echoed from? Can you change it?

The problem here is you uploaded your site to the server, but you left a lot of references to files that were in your localhost. That won't work anymore, because I don't have those images in my localhost. All the references must go to your server now.

Comment: i seted them before but their refrences were changed,how ever i seted manually again, but what about the colors? my headers color is green,but it shows white,and the fonts? my problem is mainly about the css